# Problems with cosmos auth and Identity manager integration

Tags: fiware, fiware-cosmos

I want to integrate cosmos-auth with Idm GE.
Config for node.js application is:

```
{
"host": "192.168.4.180",
"port": 13000,
"private_key_file": "key.pem",
"certificate_file": "cert.pem",
"idm": {
  "host": "192.168.4.33",
  "port": "443",
  "path": "/oauth2/token"
},
"cosmos_app": {
  "client_id": "0434fdf60897479588c3c31cfc957b6d",
  "client_secret": "a7c3540aa5de4de3a0b1c52a606b82df"
},
"log": {
  "file_name": "/var/log/cosmos/cosmos-auth/cosmos-auth.log",
  "date_pattern": ".dd-MM-yyyy"
 }
}
```

When i send HTTP POST request directly to IDM GE to url

```
https://192.168.4.33:443/oauth2/token
```

with required parameters i get ok results:

```
{
 access_token: "LyZT5DRGSn0F8IKqYU8EmRFTLo1iPJ"
 token_type: "Bearer"
 expires_in: 3600
 refresh_token: "XiyfKCHrIVyludabjaCyGqVsTkx8Sf"
}
```

But when i curl the cosmos-auth node.js application

```
curl -X POST "https://192.168.4.180:13000/cosmos-auth/v1/token" -H 
"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d   
"grant_type=password&username=idm&password=idm" -k
```

I get next result:

```
{"statusCode":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"An internal server error occurred"}
```

Has anyone encountered something similar?
What could be the problem?

Comment: The error you are getting is just a forwarding of the error sent by the IdM to cosmos-auth. Please, can you check the IdM logs in order to find a more detailed explanation about what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error i made was using unsigned certificate.How clumsy of me.
So either sign the certificate or insert additional element in options object (rejectUnauthorized: false)

```
var options = {
    host : host,
    port : port,
    path : path,
    method : method,
    headers: headers,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};
```

or in the beginning of the file insert:

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';
```

Ofcourse this is only temporary solution until we use fully signed cert.
Anyways error handling and logs in cosmos-auth node.js app should show a little bit more.